# Not sure how to declare this has_many polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model, that may have many activities ( I'm keeping track of some of the actions performed by my users, for statistical purposes )

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :histories,:through => :activities # ?
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :history, :polymorphic => true
end

class BrowsingHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :histories
end

class LoginHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :histories
end

...
```

The `Activity` class has a `history_type:string` , a `history_id:integer` and a `user_id:integer`, and I want it to be able to hold `BrowsingHistory` or `LoginHistory` objects.

I've worked pretty little with polymorphic associations, and from what I have thus far, I keep getting the error: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError:Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#histories' on the polymorphic object 'History#history'`. I read through some of the related questions on this topic, but I cannot figure out a solution.

EDIT: I think I got it ( console tests seem to work ), could you please confirm?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :login_histories,:through => :activities,:source => :history,:source_type => "LoginHistory"
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :history, :polymorphic => true
end

class BrowsingHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :history
  has_many :users,:through => :activities
end

class LoginHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :history
  has_many :users,:through => :activities
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :login_histories,:through => :activities,:source => :history,:source_type => "LoginHistory"
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :history, :polymorphic => true
end

class BrowsingHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :history
  has_many :users,:through => :activities
end

class LoginHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities,:as => :history
  has_many :users,:through => :activities
end
```